# Adding Noise to LSTM Weights in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a tensorflow model which consists of several RNNs looking at different data, which then gets combined and fed through an LSTM. I have implemented methods to add noise to the weights in the RNNs and LSTM:

```
def _add_weight_noise(self):
    tvars = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
    noises = {}
    for v in tvars:
        if 'kernel' in v.name:
            val = self._Sess.run(v.name)
            noise = self._Sess.run(self.random_noise(v.shape, weight_noise))
            noises[v.name] = noise
            new_val = val + noise
            assigner = tf.assign(v, new_val)
            self._Sess.run(assigner)
    self._noises = noises
```

where weight_noise is a float (default 0.01), and

```
def random_noise(self, shape, noise):
    return tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=noise)
```

*self._Sess* is where is the tensorflow session stored in the class. I call

```
self._Sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

before the first call to *_add_weight_noise()*

I call *_add_weight_noise()* before running the optimizer/accuracies etc. on the current batch, and I remove the weight noise before going on to the next batch in the training data.

```
def _remove_weight_noise(self):
    tvars = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
    for v in tvars:
        if 'kernel' in v.name:
            noise = self._noises[v.name]
            val = self._Sess.run(v.name)

            new_val = val - noise
            assigner = tf.assign(v, new_val)
            new_value = self._Sess.run(assigner)
```

I tested this on a small toy example and believe this to work (the variable values got updated). However, I have increased *weight_noise* up to around 20.0 on my actual data and model, and there doesn't seem to be any noticeable difference in validation accuracy, but I would expect it to be very low.

Does anybody know why this wouldn't work, or point me to code which has implemented adding weight noise to LSTMs (I've checked but couldn't find any examples).